# WPF - Mainwindow loads before splash progressbar shows completion, and the splash window doesnt close when done

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, splash-screen

I have created a splash window and mainwindow. I want to load a splash screen before the main window opens and show a scrollbar of the progress.

I have successfully created a splash window that loads first, and the progress bar shows progress, however the mainwindow loads before the progressbar is done, and the splash screen wont close when the progress is complete. I have the following code in my app.xaml.cs

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Splash splash = new Splash();
        splash.Show();
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(i);
        }
        foreach (System.Windows.Window swindow in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            (swindow as Splash).Close();
        }
    }

    public void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int progressstatus = e.ProgressPercentage;
        foreach (System.Windows.Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.GetType() == typeof(Splash))
            {
                (window as Splash).prgProgress.Value = progressstatus;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `_DoWork` method will most likely throw an exception in the `foreach` before it gets to closing the Splash. (1) Frame the whole body of the _DoWork method in a try-catch clause and MessageBox any exception it catches. (2) Use the debugger to see what is really going on there in the method and to further your understanding of your code. (3) I haven't looked any deeper into your code above; this is just the first thing that caught my eye. That means, i can currently not tell if your code might contain more errors.

Comment: Also, `Thread.Sleep(i);` is a bit silly, isn't it... ;-)

Comment: Also, in your `worker_ProgressChanged` method, your `if (window.GetType() == typeof(Splash))` can be simplified to `if (window is Splash)`.

Comment: I havebeen teaching myself all this stuff, so I apologize if the following sounds dumb...

Comment: What do you mean by Try in a try-Catch clause?, not sure why thread.sleep(i) is silly, your third comment was cleaner, thanks for that... didnt really fix anything though.

Comment: `thread.sleep(i)` Why do you use `i` as sleep delay there? It makes your progress bar growing fast initially, but every progress step taking longer and longer as it grows. That is a quite silly progress bar (also known as Windows progress bars, which almost always seem to always go fast from 0% to about 90% and then spend the most time slouching from 90% to 100%)

Comment: `try { code } catch (Exception ex) { exception handling code }` If you don't know about exception handling with `try`-`catch` blocks, i suggest to spend some time with a tutorial teaching you the ropes with regard to exception handling...

Comment: Also, a little hint with regard to your problem with `_DoWork`: The fix to your problem you can actually find when looking at the code of the  `_ProgressChanged` method. I don't want to say it directly, because i want to encourage you to use the debugger, which is the most essential and one of the most important tools to actually be able to write/produce working code (or fixing broken code) that is longer than just a dozen lines ;-)

Comment: I got it. Removed the silly thread.sleep(i), removed the foreach clause in my dowork, update the IF statement in progresschanged method to "if (window is Splash)", Added a runworkercompleted method to dispose of the worker, and in my mainwindow load method, added the close action for the splash window.